# water heater gas

Tags: water, heater

I lit the pilot and the burner kicked on nicely, when I went to replace the safety/dust pilot access cover, I bumped the pilot tube and thermocouple ever so slightly and the gas valve clicke off, click. Does this sound like the thermocouple?

Comment: what did you do after the gas valve shut off?

Comment: I just left it alone and decided to ask around.

Comment: are you sure that the gas valve shutting off when you bumped the pilot tube was not a coincidence?

Comment: I heard it distinctly and the burner clicked off when I bumped the items.

Comment: you can never be sure that the gas shut off because you bumped the pilot tube until it shuts off the second time when you tap the pilot tube again

Comment: The main burner was going nicely. Are you saying it sounds like thermocouple? or something else?

Comment: please re-read what i wrote ..... which part do you not understand?

Comment: Is the thermocouple loose where it connects to the gas valve? Or is that connection snug?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the thermocouple but what is the question? You could have knocked it out of the flame but that usually takes a second or 2 , you could have damaged it or loosened it from the gas valve. Relight the pilot and make sure the thermocouple is in the flame. If it is let it run for a few minutes just to make sure things are good. When lighting gas fired pilot based equipment I normally turn the temp up so it needs to run prior to putting it on run. At that point when putting on run wait 30 seconds if it is still running you are good to go. If the gas shuts off it is probably a bad thercoumple. So make sure it is in the flame and wait a little while after changing from pilot to run. It just may be a timing issue and you thought you did something but it just took the TC that long to change modes and turn off the valve.

Comment: That is the question, TC or not? I will proceed with your advice

Comment: Probably TC they can take from a few seconds to surround 30 for the gas valve to switch states that's why I turn up the heat to make sure it is trying to run when going from pilot to run if it continues to run for a few minutes turn the heat down so the burner turns off, now if the pilot goes out it is probably not centered in the well or a weak flame I have seen moisture in the gas line has caused havoc with pilots as another possible issue.